# How can I make python change the characters in a batch file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

I'm making a script that changes your dns and then pings a website to test latency and I've created a list with all the DNS and I want to use an external batch script to change the dns. However, I'm reasonably new to python and I don't know how to make python take data from the list and replace it in the batch file. This would help me very much, thank you!

**Python script **

```
from tcp_latency import measure_latency

host = input("Enter host: ")

def pinger():
    latency = sum(measure_latency(host, port=80, runs=10, timeout=2.5))
    latency = latency/10
    print("Your average latency is",latency)

dns = ["1.1.1.1","1.0.0.1","8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4","9.9.9.9","149.112.112.112","208.67.222.222","208.67.220.220","8.26.56.26","8.20.247.20","185.228.168.9","185.228.169.9"]
```

**Batch script**

```
@echo off
cls
for /F "skip=3 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G in ('netsh interface show interface') DO (
    IF "%%H"=="Disconnected" netsh interface set interface "%%J" enabled
    IF "%%H"=="Connected" netsh interface set interface "%%J" enabled
    echo %%J
    netsh interface ip set dns %%J static 1.1.1.1
)
```

I haven't tried any approaches just yet

Answer (score 0):

Simple string replacement should work nicely

```
dns = ["1.1.1.1","1.0.0.1","8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4","9.9.9.9","149.112.112.112","208.67.222.222","208.67.220.220","8.26.56.26","8.20.247.20","185.228.168.9","185.228.169.9"]

# Assumes .bat and .py scripts are in the same directory
bat_file = "tester.bat"

# Read original .bat file
with open(bat_file, "r") as fs:
    bat_str = fs.read()

base_name = bat_file.split(".")[0]
for dns_ip in dns:
    new_bat_str = bat_str.replace("1.1.1.1", dns_ip)
    # Parse new name for .bat file
    new_bat_file = f"{base_name}_dns_{dns_ip.replace('.', '')}.bat"
    with open(new_bat_file, "w") as fs:
        fs.write(new_bat_str)
```